# How to send Bulk emails to list of email-addresses using RabbitMQ and Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Can anyone please share some source or can you tell how I can send bulk emails using RabbitMQ and Spring boot? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#overview).

Use an AMQP inbound channel adapter wired to to an email outbound adapter.

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlows flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(...))
                    .split( ... ) // custom splitter to generate multiple
                    .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter(...))
                    .get();
}
```